# How can I replace 40% characters from file ? C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a text file with characters like this(eg.):
**Hi man. how is going. cool. lool. love this thing. fo real. yep.no way.it's real.haha.**

The character for this is predetermined and in this case is '.' I'm supposed to be replacing 40% of this character with another character. The 40% of characters are to be chosen at random (only choosing from '.'). How would I go about finding these characters, and then replacing them?

Comment: You might want to *try* something first.

Comment: smells a bit like homework :)

Comment: If it is homework, be sure to use the homework tag to let posters know not to GIVE you the answer, but rather give you a hint so you can learn how to answer it yourself.

Comment: naaa ... it's no homework :) Believe me :)

Comment: yep, I would accept a hint here, after I count how many "." are in the document, I don't know how to choose the 4 characters randomly, that's all.

Comment: I really don't understand why this was "reported" :)

Answer (score 3):

You find the number of ., example: 20 and store the indices of . into an array
You find how many of those you want to delete: example: 8
Then you loop through the array of indices 8 times, get a random one from that array and replace that index with space. Btw, you'll need to remove the updated index from the array at each update.

Answer (score 0):

What you're wanting to do is find all of the indexes of the '.' and store them somewhere, in this case an array. Once you have all of those indexes you take the largest index and use that as the maximum for the random number generator. Divide the largest index by 40 and you have how many times you need to replace a character. Take the random number you've generated and start replacing characters at those indexes.

```
int i = 0, chr[] = 0;
while (chr[i] != -1)
{
    if (string.indexof(specifiedChar, chr[i]) != -1)
     {
      chr[i] = string.indexof(specifiedChar, chr);
      i ++; 
     }
    else
     {
      chr = -1;
     } 
}
```

chr[] will have the indexes of all of your .'s (assumingi specificedChar = '.'). i = number of '.'s. Don't take the above code as ready to roll out, but it's generally correct for your problem.

```
endInt = i;
int x = RandomNumber.Next(startInt, endInt);
```

Then replace the character at index[x] with ' '

Comment: If I've screwed something up above let me know, I'm not very well versed with c#.

Comment: Probably best to call that pseudo-code rather than saying it is C# with poor syntax.